# How to get select only one from duplicate fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have a table which looks like this:

```
TEAMNAME  | NAME | DATE_SUBMITTED | STATUS
----------+------+----------------+--------    
PLUS++    | Rick | 2017-04-04     | PENDING
PLUS++    | Elan | 2017-04-04     | PENDING
PLUS++    | Tina | 2017-04-04     | PENDING
Tornado   | Amy  | 2017-04-04     | PENDING
Tornado   | May  | 2017-04-04     | PENDING
Tornado   | Roy  | 2017-04-04     | PENDING
PhaceLook | Emma | 2017-04-04     | PENDING
PhaceLook | Tony | 2017-04-04     | PENDING
```

What I want is to produce the results below:

```
TEAMNAME  | NAME | DATE_SUBMITTED | STATUS
----------+------+----------------+--------        
PLUS++    | Rick | 2017-04-04     | PENDING
Tornado   | Roy  | 2017-04-04     | PENDING    
PhaceLook | Emma | 2017-04-04     | PENDING
```

I want to remove duplicate team names.

Here is the Code I have:

```
SELECT TEAMNAME
     , NAME
     , DATE_SUBMITTED
     , STATUS
  FROM ('SELECT DISTINCT TEAMNAME FROM phase2') phase2 
 ORDER 
    BY DATE_SUBMITTED DESC
```

Can anyone advise?

Comment: What is criteria you choose output record ? (Why "Roy"  for "Tornado") ?

Comment: How do you decide which entry to take if you have duplicates?

Comment: 'SELECT DISTINCT TEAMNAME FROM phase2' is obviously a string, right?

Comment: I only want one row for each team name. That's my criteria @OtoShavadze

Comment: Isn't it handy that DATE_SUBMITTED and STATUS are always the same.

Comment: Do you have identity/primary key column in table ?

Comment: No, because STATUS can be changed to ACCEPTED @Strawberry

Comment: I beg to differ. Clearly, that never happens. ;-)

Comment: No, I do not gave identity/primary key colomn in table @OtoShavadze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do group by on those records.

```
Select * from (SELECT TEAMNAME, max(NAME), DATE_SUBMITTED from phase2 group by TEAMNAME, DATE_SUBMITTED) a join (select teamname,status from phase2 group by teamname,status) b a.teamname=b.teamname
```

Comment: I have changed it somehow to make status to be anything pending or accepted

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH~!